# Unable to mount nfs share shared from netapp in centos 7

Tags: centos7, nfs, netapp, nfsclient

I am unable to mount nfs share from netapp in centos 7. Exports are shared to everyone from netapp
I Specifically tried in nfsversion=3 and security style to sys,none and ntlmssp but still no luck.

Below are the messages in /var/log/messages and dmesg while mounting the shares

```
kernel: RPC: server <<IP Address>> requires stronger authentication.
```

Below is the nfs mount command output

```
# mount -t nfs -o nfsversion=3 <<server IP>>:/NFS1 /nfsshare -vvv
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sat Sep  1 00:27:14 2018
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=<<server IP>>,clientaddr=<<client IP>>'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.0,addr=<<server IP>>,clientaddr=<<client IP>>'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=<<server IP>>'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying <<server IP>> prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying <<server IP>> prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 635
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting <<server IP>>:/NFSVOL
```

Please let me know how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like permission related. Make sure cent os is added in your netapp system as a client.